# Skyrim - Is There a Fix for Illia's gear bug?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

This is an issue specific to [Illia](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illia), and I was wondering if there is a fix for it. I've done extensive research and have found the problem multiple times, but no fix.

Illia is a mage that you can recruit as a follower after doing her quest. She is one of two female mages that specializes in both destruction and restoration (the reason I want her). The problem is that her default gear is a blue hooded robe. For some reason, this makes it so that she cannot wear chestpieces that you trade with her. If she equips a helmet, she will take off the robe (because it fills both slots), but she still won't be able to put any chestpiece on. This basically means that she's either stuck naked with a helmet, gloves, and boots; or a crappy blue robe.

Is there any fix for this? It seems like she's basically acting like the head and chest armor slots are permanently merged together.

I am using the AFT mod (Amazing Follower Tweaks). However, this bug is part of Illia, so I doubt AFT has anything to do with it. I am running on a PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Xbox or PC?

As the Wiki quotes,

> *"Players may experience problems when trying to have Illia equip new items, due to AI requiring armor of higher rating. Using the console on the PC version, she can be forced to wear armor for the duration of her time as a follower*."

Just as it also mentions that,

> "*The only way to make Illia change her default robes is by giving headwear, such as helmets or circlets, to her*."

So if you're using an Xbox playing vanilla Skyrim, there's no way to fix this problem. However if you're using the PC version of Skyrim, you can use console commands to force her to wear armor for the duration of her time as a follower.

To do so, do the following steps in order:

**First,** open console with the "~" key.

**Second,** click on NPC and type "inv" without quotes. This shows you the codes for the armor that they have on.

**Thirdly,** Locate the pieces (and their code) that you want to remove and type "removeitem (codehere) 1" It should look something like this, "removeitem 4d3f5 1"

NOTE: [You must leave at least one original piece of armor on them in order for the clothes to not reset back to what they were originally wearing. I like to leave boots or gloves as they don't have as much impact on overall appearance as the chest piece and helmet.]

**Fourthly,** To give them new armor, look up the code for what armor you want to give them, either from a list or by typing "help keyword 4". For example,to look for a Whiterun's guard armor type "help whiterun 4". You can use the page up and down keys to navigate.

**Fifth,**  Once you find the code open the console, click on the NPC, type "additem (codehere) 1". For example, "additem 4d3dd".

The big thing to remember is to leave one original piece on them.

Comment: I didn't think simply consoling her out of the bug would work, but it did like a charm. Thank you very much! I didn't even need to add items through the console. Once I removed the robes I was able to trade armor with her normally, and she equipped it normally.